# disable errors while reading csv file

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Does dask dataframe pass the **error bad lines** parameter to pandas DataFrame class?
In other words, this does not seem to work because I get an error when I try to run groupby query.

```
df = dd.read_csv('s3://todel162xx/some.csv' , error_bad_lines=False, storage_options = {'anon':False})
```

There are only 1 or 2 lines in the csv file that may have different datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dask.dataframe.read_csv passes through the `error_bad_lines` keyword argument